# number of times a statement gets executed in terms of n

Tags: java, big-o, analytics

I want the true way to get the number of times that a statement in my code gets executed in terms of `n`.

For example: in this code, how many times do `MyStatement1` and `MyStatement2`  get executed, and why?

```
sum = 0;
for (i=1; i<=n; i*=2) {
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        sum++; // MyStatement1
    }

    for (k=1; j<=n; k++) {
        sum++; // MyStatement2
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that second inner `for` loop infinite or not? `j <= n`?

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza  how can i count it

Comment: do you have a typo in the last for? shouldn't it be `k<=n` ?

Comment: @Klaimmore I think   j <= n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MyStatement1**: O(n)

Precise number of executions is based on sum of [geometrical progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). The outer loop will be executed `m` times where `2^m = n` thus `m = log2(n)`

the inner loop will be executed `1 + 2 + 4 +... + 2^m` times. That's a sum of a geometrical progression:

```
(1-2^m)/(1-2) = O(2^m) = O(2^log2(n)) = O(n)
```

**MyStatement2**: infinity

at the time of execution of the 2nd inner loop `j=log2(n)`. Since that is less than `n` the condition will never be satisfied ending up as an infinite loop.

Comment: Careful. First `for` loop is not linear.

Answer (score 1):

Since `i` starts out less than `n` and the first `for` loop brings `j` up to `i`, then the second `for` loop is infinite. You need to change the loop condition to `k <= n` for the second loop or it is a meaningless program.